# Default Application cleared when updating application?

Tags: android, default, launch

Does any of you have the same experience and maybe a solution for this.
When developing the application each time I update it, it loses its launch by defaults settings like the one shown here below:

[image: app default settings android]

After updating the software to the latest version, it has lost the launch by default settings.

I can't figure out how to keep the settings (should this not happen by default)?. As eventually for each update you do not want the users to select the application each time as default.